# Rely on JPA to use sub class when using @Inheritance and two times same @DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, discriminator

I have following entitys:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@DiscriminatorValue("Company")
public class Company {
    ... (lot of attributes)
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Company")
public class LargeCompany extends Company {
    ... (a few not required attributes)
}
```

The Company entity lies in a separate project and should be extendable (usually just by one subclass).

When I use @Inheritance by default JPA creates only one table with all attributes from Company and all sub classes. To separate all these different types of instances JPA
uses the @DiscriminatorValue which is usually different for each class.

I realized that it doesn't cause problems if I use same @DiscriminatorValue for both classes (entities). That would make it much easier to use:

The separat project can be responsible for creating Companies and storing them (UI, Validation, etc.). In the next step my project could load these Companies and without
an additional step I get LargeCompany objects.

I verified with several integration tests that this works (when entityManager is cleared) but I'm not sure if I can really rely on that "feature"? Is there probably a better way?

Btw. I'm using hibernate 4.2.0

---

one of the working tests:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Company company = new Company("TEST");
    em.persist(company);
    em.flush();
    em.clear();     // required!!

    company = em.createQuery("from Company").getFirstResult();
    assertEquals(LargeCompany.class, company.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading a Company that is not a LargeCompany? That looks completely wrong to me.

Comment: Does large company have additional data in the database (in relation to company) or are you just extending it with additional logic?

Comment: also some (not required) fields

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert one Object in one application to another object in another machine? In this case, it will work. If we talk about its background, in backend (in DB) it create one column for discrimination of row and that row be form to particular java object based on that discrimination value. As you are using same discrimination value in two application accessing same DB, its actually transporting the object from one application to another application. But, If you try to use same discrimination value in single application then you will be in trouble. Firstly, it should give error and if its not giving error then its converted one of your object to another object without your knowledge. So, be careful when using it in same application.